# How can i find if one of my result in a foreach is equal of my variable?

Tags: php

I have a foreach, inside i could get 1 or more information per person . After i have a small condition, i display the nom_gerant, prenom_gerant only if it's true, i want to add a small condition to test if the prenom_gerant + the name_gerant equal one of the result of my foreach.

For instance :

Mr Brian Millot

Mr George Michael

If the variable $nom_gerant + $prenom_gerant equal one of of my result of my foreach, i don't want to display it.

if $nom_gerant + $prenom_gerant equal Brian Millot for instance .

I guess i have to use in_array ?

```
<?php 

    foreach ($liste_assoc as $assoc) {

    echo $assoc['Civ.'].' ';

    echo $assoc['Nom'].' ';

    echo $assoc['Prénom'].'<br />';

    } ?>

    <?php if($nom_gerant){ ?>

    <?php echo $civ_gerant .' '.$nom_gerant .' '. $prenom_gerant; ?> <br /><br /><br /><br />

    <?php } ?>
```

EDIT :

I get these informations with the code i put .

Mme. BUENO Sabine (foreach)

Mme. BUENO SABINE (second part)

I want to get Mme. BUENO Sabine one time .

In this case it' the same person but it could be a different person .

Comment: Your code here isn't doing very much, you're looping through an array, echoing variables then testing to see if a variable is set. What is the purpose of the code? Is it to get a list of employees and their managers?

Comment: *Plus,* `$nom_gerant` is an undefined variable. I take it this as being pseudo-code. Are you by chance querying a DB?

Comment: Yes, in my case i get a list of assoc, in it, i can have some persons, these persons can be assoc and also (in some case) $gerant, it's because i don't want to display their names two times .

Comment: Could you post all the relevant parts of your code? This seems to be missing some parts.

Comment: If you're not too far in your project, you could make use of [`in_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)

Comment: Are you looking for something like `if( ($assoc['Civ.'] .' '.$assoc['Nom'] .' '. $assoc['Prénom']) == ($civ_gerant .' '.$nom_gerant .' '. $prenom_gerant) ) { // don't echo } else { echo ...}`

Comment: I put exatly what i get with my code . I edited my post .

Comment: Sean, yes something like this but in my case with the foreach the result depends .

Answer (score 1):

Your question doesn't seems very clear but here is an answer base on what I understood:

```
foreach($liste_assoc as $assoc)
{
    if($assoc['Prenom'].$assoc['Nom'] == 'Nom du gérant ICI!!The names you want to compare' || $assoc['Prenom'].$assoc['Nom'] == 'Autre nom de gérant à comparer!' || $assoc['Prenom'].$assoc['Nom'] == $thingstocompare)//could also use a var//Pourrait aussi utiliser une variable.
    {
        //Code to execute in case the last name and first name match
        //Le code a éxécuter quand les nom et prénoms sont égual aux valeurs a comparer.
    }
    else
    {
        //Code to execute when they don't match
        //Code à éxecuter lorsque les valeurs ne sont pas les valeurs à comparer.
    }
}
```

Or to check if something is in an array you could use:

```
if(in_array('Nom du gérant' , $list_assoc))
{
    //Code to execute if its in the array
    //Code à éxecuter s'il est dans la liste.
}
```

**--EDIT--** Sorry I realise that the OP was using french in his code so I tried posting something everyone could understand.

Comment: ...which is [`what I thought`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25166251/how-can-i-find-if-one-of-my-result-in-a-foreach-is-equal-of-my-variable#comment39182066_25166251) as well ;)

Comment: @Fred-ii- Not surprise that you thought about the same answer as me! You seems to be looking to answer pretty much the same answers as me all the time XD I see your name all the time XD

Comment: [`in_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) is such a great function and for so many reasons while being quite versatile. Let's see if OP will accept your answer ;) *"I see your name all the time"* - I try ;) I usually like commenting first to see if I can fix OP's issues.